# Why Jest passed all test but still throw an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I added a feature to my code, but when I run all the test, all the test runs successfully, but Jest still throws an internal error with this message:

```
Ran all test suites.
the_path\node_modules\expect\build\index.js:303
      throw error;
      ^

JestAssertionError: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "node-user-settings"
Received: "null"
```

I created another .js file and called the code I wanted to test with Jest and it runs properly.
Now, I don't understand why Jest throws an internal error.

This is the test that generates the error.

```
  test("asynchronously gets a value, using callbacks without optional filename", () => {
    settings.getState_c("moduleName", null, null, (err, data) => {
      expect(err).toBe(null);
      expect(data).toBe("node-user-settings");
    });
  });
```

Comment: I think you need to tell Jest that you're testing an asynchronous function: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Comment: hey! I added async to the callback, but it still throws the error

Comment: I think you want to use `done` instead of `async` unless you're returning a `Promise` from your asynchronous function.

Comment: work!! Thank you. You should post it as an answer so that I can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell Jest that you're testing an asynchronous function: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous.

Use [`done`](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks) instead of `async` if your function does not return a Promise, but is asynchronous.